# How to Load the Earnings Calendar data from TradingView link and into Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to load the Earnings Calendar data from TradingView link and load into Dataframe.

```
Link: https://in.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-india/earnings/
Filter-1: Data for "This Week"
```

[image]

I am not able to select the Tab "This Week". Any help ?

Answer is Closed so posting here:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 50000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('display.width', 10000)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://in.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-india/earnings/")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[.='This Week']").click()
time.sleep(5)

visible_columns = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.tv-screener__content-pane thead th:not([class*=i-hidden])')
data_field = [c.get_attribute('data-field') for c in visible_columns]

header = [c.text.split('\n')[0] for c in visible_columns]
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='tv-screener__content-pane']//tbody/tr")

columns = []
for field in data_field:
    column = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='tv-screener__content-pane']//tbody/tr/td[@data-field-key='{field}']")
    columns.append([col.text.replace('\n',' - ') for col in column])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(header, columns)))
print(df)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that there are few hidden columns characterized by the class `i-hidden`. So as first thing we select only the visible columns with the css selector `:not([class*=i-hidden])`. Then we get the attribute `data-field` of these columns, so that we can select the corresponding values in the rows. Examples of values for this attribute are

```
name
market_cap_basic
earnings_per_share_forecast_next_fq
eps_surprise_fq
```

Next we get the header of the table and the rows. Then we loop over the data-field to get all the cell values in each column. Finally we create a dataframe from a dictionary having the header as keys and the columns as values.

```
visible_columns = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.tv-screener__content-pane thead th:not([class*=i-hidden])')
data_field = [c.get_attribute('data-field') for c in visible_columns]
header = [c.text.split('\n')[0] for c in visible_columns]
rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='tv-screener__content-pane']//tbody/tr")
columns = []

for field in data_field:
    column = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f"//div[@class='tv-screener__content-pane']//tbody/tr/td[@data-field-key='{field}']")
    columns.append([col.text.replace('\n',' - ') for col in column])

pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(header, columns)))
```

Output

[image]

Comment: How to select data for "This Week"

Comment: @Rohit You can do it with `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[.='This Week']").click()`